# Saving and auto running a program in python

Tags: python, file

I am stuck on trying to get my program to auto run after being saved. i was wondering if there was a way of doing this in a program. i have tried something like this...

```
y = 0
with open('File.py',"w") as fh:
    fh.write('''
y = 0
with open('File.txt',"r") as fh:
    job=fh.read()
while True:
    y += 1
    file = open(str(y)+'.py', "w")
    file.write(job)
    file.close()
    y = int(y)''')
with open('File.py',"r") as fh:
    job=fh.read()
while True:
    y += 1
    file = open(str(y)+'.py', "w")
    file.write(job)
    file.close()
    y = int(y)
```

This seems to make lots and lots of files, thats fine thats what i want it to do, but i also want it to run these files after being saved.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do that, but what are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: [Built-in function execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) may help you on this.

Comment: what's you purpose of doing this..?

Comment: Well what I want is like a self copying python file and when it copies this python file into another I want that to run, so it duplicates really quickly, its my way of showing how bacteria work. Basically my nerdy science project